# True identity of Wonder Woman

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

When researching more about Wonder Woman depicted in *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice* I found slightly contradictory information about her background in the comics.

- On Wiki, it said: Wonder Woman is a warrior princess of the Amazons (which are based on the Amazons of Greek mythology) and is known in her homeland as Princess Diana of Themyscira.
- And I just read somewhere: Wonder Woman is the offspring of Zeus and Hippolyta and as such should be at least a demigod.

Which one is true? Or both? If she is the offspring os Zeus, does that make her immortal? What is her background in the DC films released as part of the DC Extended Universe and on what comic origin is it based?

Comment: http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_(Diana_Prince)

Comment: Is this actually about the DC Extended Universe (as tagged that way) or about any other specific movie incarnation of this character or are you asking about the general comics character? In the former case you might want to specify the question a little more and in the latter case I'm afraid this might be off-topic here and you'd have better luck on [scifi.se].

Comment: *"After the 2011 relaunch of Wonder Woman as part of DC's The New 52 publishing initiative, Wonder Woman's origin is revised as she discovers she is the daughter of Zeus. Zeus and Hippolyta engaged in combat, and their fight ended with the couple making love, and thus Diana was conceived*"

Comment: She is either a demigod ( from zeus as per new 52 comics / maybe hades as per DCAU) and made of clay as per old comics. She is kind of immortal. In DCEU nobody know for sure yet.

Comment: What in those two statements do you think contradict each other?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Now that *Wonder Woman* has come out, we can confirm that Wonder Woman in *Batman v Superman* is Princess Diana of Themyscira, using the alias Diana Prince that was given to her by Steve Trevor.

The movie explores her origins as well. Hippolyta tells Diana that she was sculpted out of clay and given life by Zeus.

> In the end, we learn that (like in the *New 52* continuity, this is just a story told to cover Diana's real story -- she is the daughter of Zeus and a demigod in her own right.

---

The short answer is: we don't know.

We know almost nothing about Wonder Woman in the DC Extended Universe, other than her name (someone calls her Mrs. Prince at one point, but I'm not even sure she was called Diana ever.)

Her identity in the comics has changed multiple times over the years, and we don't yet know which one of those stories Zach Synder's team has picked for her. He seems to be following the more recent versions of the characters, in which case she would be a demigod (this is her New 52 origin).

We *do* know that she is immortal, or at least close to it, as she hasn't aged any since the photograph take of her ~100 years ago. But that doesn't really narrow down the answer, because most of her DC comics origin stories would fit there.

The answer will most likely come out during the *Wonder Woman* movie due out next year.

Comment: FYI its now confirmed: she is Princess Diana

Comment: I went to cinema on last weekend to watch Wonder Woman, and I had the answer from the movie :)

Answer (score 1):

MOVE SPOILERS AHEAD!

"On Wiki, it said: Wonder Woman is a warrior princess of the Amazons (which are based on the Amazons of Greek mythology) and is known in her homeland as Princess Diana of Themyscira.
And I just read somewhere: Wonder Woman is the offspring of Zeus and Hippolyta and as such should be at least a demigod."

in the DCEU, the new Wonder Woman movie established that she is both.

1. She, as daughter of hippolyta, is the Princess of Themyscira.
2. She, as daughter of Zeus, a god, and hippolyta, an amazon, is at least some level of demigod.

Comment: I'd quibble with this. In the DCEU Hippolyta raised her (so she's her "mother" in that sense), but her entire essence came from Zeus. So she's not a demi-god, but a full-blown god.

Comment: They say that she's the child of Zeus and Hippolyta, if I'm not mistaken. Will need to wait until it's out of theaters to confirm

Comment: Define "they". In the movie its pretty explicit that the life force all came from Zeus, and all Hippolyta did was scoop up some clay (as directed).

Comment: @T.E.D. Ares's exact phrase was "Zeus left the child he had with the Queen of the Amazons as a weapon against me." The phrasing is ambiguous, (did have "have" a child with Hippolyta or did he merely "leave" a child with Hippolya) but certainly strongly suggests that Diana was Hippolyta's child as well. The clay story was a lie Hippolyta told Diana to conceal her real identity.