# Why does Wonder Woman say "goodbye brother" to Ares?

Tags: dialogue, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

When Ares reveals himself to Diana in *Wonder Woman*, just after she finds out that her sword is powerless against him, he says "Oh my dear child".

Then, Diana tells him:

> Goodbye brother.

before she [kills him](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78023/did-wonder-woman-kill-ares).

Why did she say that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Was Hippolyta telling the truth about Diana's origin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74417/was-hippolyta-telling-the-truth-about-dianas-origin) or [True identity of Wonder Woman](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/51089/63559) - both Ares and Diana are Children of Zeus, so Ares is her brother

Comment: Clay-geneses are typical in Greek Mythology, so I don't know what to believe @Jenayah :O :P But so are Zeus' affairs.... ;) Thanks! Wonder why I failed to locate the duplicate myself, maybe I used the wrong keywords...

Comment: I'm not sure they are entirely duplicates.  Yes, the answer (that her father is Zeus in DC mythology) is somewhat a duplicate, but the question is not.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because in the DC mythology, they share [Zeus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeus_(DC_Comics)) as a father.

Originally the comic book character of Diana Prince / Wonder Woman was 'created out of clay and brought to life' but that was changed in later comics to Zeus being her father.

Ares is a son of Zeus in both DC and Greek mythology.

So, although their age differs massively, they are half-sibling.

Comment: This (that Zeus is her father and that they are thereby half-siblings) is also fairly clearly established in the movie. One needn't rely on knowing much about the DC universe to understand why she called him that.

Comment: The being who "creates you out of clay and brings you to life" could be described as someones "parent".

Comment: @Yakk .... indeed yes.

Comment: Who is *her* father in Greek mythology?

Comment: @Michael Are you asking who is *Wonder Woman*'s father in Greek mythology? I must have missed that part of the Illiad.

Comment: @JBChouinard I guess the closest equivalent might be Artemis, which would make the answer... Zeus!

Comment: @Michael Well, Artemis is a whole other DC character. As far as I know Diana is not based on any particular Greek goddess.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippolyta, Ares was the father of Hippolyta, who was (according to DC) the mother of Wonder Woman. So that makes Ares both brother and grandfather. Greek mythology is weird.

Comment: Umm @Phlarx, IIRC`, Hippolyta didn't have a daughter whatsoever in **Greem Mythology**. Greek mythology is **awesome** IMHO. :) Michael, when the Romans metaphrased the Greek Gods in order to "integrate" them to their culture, Artemis was renamed to Diana.

Comment: @Phlarx: Greek mythology has Zeus and his wife Hera being siblings as well, making Zeus father *and uncle* of all his children. As he sires a child with one of his daughters as well (Eris -> Limos), plus a couple of other weirdnesses, that Olympos family tree is truly something to behold. :-D

Comment: @gsamaras There's no rule that something cannot be both weird and awesome! According to DC, Wonder Woman's official title is "Princess Diana of Themyscira, Daughter of Hippolyta", that's where that was pulled from (though I admit "daughter" could also be interpreted in ways other than biological). This only serves to show that there may not even be a 'right' answer here.

Comment: Agreed @Phlarx! It seems that DC Mythology diverts from Authentic Hellenic Mythology in this matter, I mean Diana was the Daughter of Hippolyta in that movie, but not in actual Hellenic Mythology..